# Value is not Accessible in MVC JsonResult from Angular Function

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I've a model class like this:-

```
public class InternShip
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }

}
```

Now I've a view in which I've created ng-click event:-

```
<a ng-click="IntrnDetail(r.ID)" style="cursor:pointer"><h5>{{r.Name}}</h5></a>
```

On Click my value passes to my angular file InternShip.js where it is handeled by function:-

```
$scope.IntrnDetail = function (InternID) {
        window.location.href = '/Home/InternDetail/' + InternID;
    }
```

Now My Controller (HomeController) has ActionResult(InternDetail) as:-

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult InternDetail(string InterID)
    {
        List<InternShip> Intern = new List<InternShip>();
        int IntID = Convert.ToInt32(InterID);
        using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
        {
            Intern = db.Interns.Where(x => x.ID == IntID).ToList();
        }

        return new JsonResult{ Data= Intern, JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    }
```

But the problem is although value is coming inside InternID of InternShip.js but in JsonResult (InternDetail) InterID is getting null. I don't know why is that happening.

Please HELP!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with your route since default mvc route is something like

```
{action}/{controller}/id(optional)
```

means that when you pass

```
"Home/Index/3"
```

the route will set the value of id to 3
now your action result parameter is not `id` but `interID` so either do

```
window.location.href ='/Home/InternDetail?InterID='+InternID ;
```

or change the `interID` to `ID`

```
public JsonResult InternDetail(int ID)
```

you can also configure your route

Comment: That did it . Thanks for the explaination.